# Check if 2 cells are blank excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Im trying to write a formula that will check if 2 cells in a row are blank and if they are / arnt output true / false. Ive been working with `isblank()` and have put together this :

`=IF(ISBLANK(L2) AND ISBLANK(N2), blank, not blank)` but it returns a formula parse error, any ideas why this might be ?

Im doing this inside of google spreadsheets, so ideally id prefer not to use vba.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using an `AND` operator from a language that Excel can't compile.

In Excel it's an `AND` function with syntax:

> AND(logical1, [logical2], ...)

Also the returns, being strings, need to be within double quotes in Excel functions so:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(L2),ISBLANK(N2)),"blank", "not blank")
```

Answer (score 1):

`=if(and(isblank(L2),isblank(N2)),"blank","notblank")`